# how to show similar points based on two classes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(DES = c("AAAAA", "ABBBB", "BBDDD", "CHDDD", "NMHH", 
"YNNN", "UUUU", "IMMM", "TTSGG", "MHDDD", "IIKKKKK", "UDDDD", 
"AAAAA", "ABBBB"), Name = c("AB1", "TH1", "TH2", "HUA", "HUA1", 
"UMA", "YIN", "YIM", "IUMH", "YIMH", "YIH", "TH2", "AB1", "TH1"
), data = c(1.399260301, 1.435057306, 1.515715678, 1.157216398, 
1.452347714, 1.172466387, 1.16325675, 2.614138423, 0.895228818, 
1.571925745, 1.717242238, 1.572841664, 0.924094104, 1.59458932
), Exact = c(0.000536206, 0.000910058, 0.001145037, 0.00114666, 
0.001883335, 0.002365192, 0.002548559, 0.003406673, 0.004232483, 
0.005164572, 0.006269242, 0.006741774, 0.009565493, 0.009581586
), Class = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

I am trying to make a plot with two different class and show those that are common with two different color and their names

to plot it I simply do this

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = data, y = -log10(Exact)))+
  geom_point(colour="blue",size=0.5)
```

now I want to plot them with two different colors

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = data, y = -log10(Exact)))+
  geom_point(colour="blue",size=0.5)+
  geom_point(data=df$Class ==1 , aes(x=data, y=-log10(Exact)), colour="red", size=2)+
  geom_point(data=df$Class ==2, aes(x=data, y=-log10(Exact)), colour="green", size=2)
```

it seems not showing , however, I want to lable those that are in common between two classes with two different colors

for examples these are common

```
AB1
TH1
TH2
YIH
```

Comment: You can use the `colour` argument on 'Class' i.e. `df %>% mutate(Class = factor(Class)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = data, y = -log10(Exact), colour = Class)) + geom_point(size = 0.5)`

Comment: @akrun
how to lable those 4 common ones with two different colors ? from Class1 and Class 2?

Comment: You can set the colours with a named vector where names are the unique values of 'Class' column as in the solution I posted below

Answer (score 0):

You can `subset` your two classes and `label` you points. To only show the same classes, you can create a seperate dataframe with only the same classes. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

same_classes <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(n() >1)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x = data, y = -log10(Exact)))+
  geom_point(colour="blue",size=0.5) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, Class ==1) , aes(x=data, y=-log10(Exact)), colour="red", size=2) +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, Class ==2), aes(x=data, y=-log10(Exact)), colour="green", size=2) +
  geom_text(data = same_classes, aes(x = data, y = -log10(Exact), label = Name), hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this one lable all , I only need those that are in common

Comment: @nik, I updated my answer! Now it only shows the same classes.

Comment: @nik, Is this what you wanted, or should it be different? Let me know if I can help you.